# Angular new router template mapping

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I'm converting a application from ui-router to the new Angular router to make it easier to migrate to Angular 2.0 in the future. I'm not afraid of breaking changes as I don't have many components yet.

My problem is that it doesn't load the templates to in my components.
I have structured the code to be in

```
/components/<component-name>/<component-name>.html
```

as an example

```
/components/checkout/checkout.html
```

This is my route.config:

```
$router.config([
    {path: '/', redirectTo: '/checkout'},
    {path: '/checkout', component: {main: 'checkout', search: 'search', toolbar: 'toolbar'}},
    {path: '/driver', component: {main: 'DriversView', search: 'search', toolbar: 'toolbar'}}
]);
```

It loads the controllers that should be loaded but it doesn't even try to load the templates, I checked the network tab in chrome dev tools and there is no .html. Anything I need to think about that I might have missed?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't even try to load the templates"? Did you check the network tab in dev tools?

Comment: Yeah, no .html in my network tab in dev tools, will clarify question.

Comment: It seems I managed to solve it, not totally sure what did it but there seemed to be something strange in the loading of templates. Also, don't name your components with a capitalized first letter, then it will look for a folder name like "-drivers-view" instead you want to name it driversView to get the folder name "drivers-view"

Comment: I'm following the exact same structure, except first I'm making components and loading them with ui-router. Even simple string based templates like:                 template: "<div>Hi there</div>" are not rendering.